# How to use conditional statements inside ForEach in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I use conditional statements inside ForEach in swiftUI or is it possible?

**What is Expected**

*My expectation is showing the correct food Items according to the ID(foodItem), Since i'm able to get all the food items inside the model class*

> Use-Case

*I'm using a ForEach inside a GridView to display show different food Items, I have all my food items inside my model, and am passing a variable "foodItem" so, that the grid view get to know what type of food I need to show*

> Current Issue

Since I have the id for food Item I'm using a conditional statement inside the forEach to show the correct foodItem, but the Xcode is giving me an error, 2 errors.

> Code of what I have done

```
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                                ForEach(
                                    if(foodType == 1){
                                        model.foodItems
                                    }else if ( foodType == 2){
                                        model.drinkItems
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        model.dessers
                                    }
 id: \.self) { item in
                            VStack{
                                GridImageView(item.image)
                                Text(item.food)
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
```

**My Model class**

```
import Foundation

class Model: ObservableObject {
    let foodItems = [
        FoodItems(food: "Rice",
                  image: "ricee"),
        FoodItems(food: "Fish Curry",
                  image: "fishcurry"),
        FoodItems(food: "Fish Curry 2",
                  image: "Fish Curry 2"),
        FoodItems(food: "Egg Curry",
                  image: "eggcurry")
    ]

    let drinkItems = [
        DrinkItems(food: "Cola",
                   image: "cola"),
        DrinkItems(food: "Pepsi",
                   image: "pepsi"),
        DrinkItems(food: "Limca",
                   image: "limca"),
    ]

    let dessers = [
        Desserts(food: "strawberry",
                 image: "strawberry"),
        Desserts(food: "chocolate",
                 image: "chocolate"),
    ]
}
```

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different approach than trying to use conditional statements that do not work inside a `ForEach`.

Use a general model for your data (`Food`), and use a `filter` to select the
`type` you want to display, such as in this example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    @State var foodType = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        // for testing
        Button("Change type") {
            foodType = foodType + 1
            if foodType > 3 { foodType = 1 }
        }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        
        ForEach(model.foodItems.filter{$0.type == foodType}) { item in
            VStack{
                Text(item.food)
                // image....
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Food: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var type: Int
    var food: String
    var image: String
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    let foodItems = [
        Food(type: 1, food: "Rice", image: "ricee"),
        Food(type: 1, food: "Fish Curry", image: "fishcurry"),
        Food(type: 1, food: "Fish Curry 2", image: "Fish Curry 2"),
        Food(type: 1, food: "Egg Curry", image: "eggcurry"),
        Food(type: 2, food: "Cola", image: "cola"),
        Food(type: 2, food: "Pepsi", image: "pepsi"),
        Food(type: 2, food: "Limca", image: "limca"),
        Food(type: 3, food: "strawberry", image: "strawberry"),
        Food(type: 3, food: "chocolate", image: "chocolate")
    ]
}
```

Better still, use enum for the `type`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, what does this `$0.type` means? Specifically "$0", sorry, i'm new to swift.

Comment: Thanks this helped, but is there any way I can do conditional checking inside forEach. see, if the situation is such that we are forced to use different different class than a same class( as in our situation ), thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a protocol here and use a an array containing items matching that protocol in your `ForEach`

Example protocol

```
protocol Food {
    var food: String { get }
    var image: String { get }
}
```

And then conform all your types to this protocol

```
struct FoodItems: Food {
    let food: String
    let image: String
}
```

and so on

Next we add a function in the model class that returns the correct kind of food given a type parameter

```
func food(type: Int) -> [Food] {
    switch type {
    case 1:
        return foodItems
    case 2:
        return drinkItems
    default:
        return dessers
    }
}
```

and then you call this function from your view

```
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
    ForEach(model.food(type: foodType), id: \.food) { item in
        VStack {
            GridImageView(item.image)
            Text(item.food)
        }
    }
}
```